# Using variance of sample to calculate unbiased estimate of population variance

Tags: sampling, unbiased-estimator, estimators, survey-sampling

I am trying to follow through the survey sampling chapter of Rice's statistics book.

Denote the sample values by $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ and the population values by $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N$ (so the population size is $N$ and sample size is $n$). $\mu$ is the population mean and $\sigma^2$ is the population variance.

Denote the distinct values assumed by the population members by $\zeta_1, \zeta_2, \ldots, \zeta_m$ and denote the number of population members that have the value $\zeta_i$ by $n_j, ~j = 1, 2, \ldots, m$.  Then, $X_i$ is a discrete random variable with probability mass function

$$\text{P}(X_i = \zeta_j) = \frac{n_j}{N}$$

Then,
$$\text{E}(X_i) = \sum_{j=1}^m \zeta_j \; \text{P}(X_i = \zeta_j) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^m n_j \zeta_j = \mu$$

$$\text{Var}(X_i) = \text{E}(X_i^2) - [\text{E}(X_i)]^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^m n_j \zeta_j^2 - \mu^2 = \sigma^2$$ since $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 = \sum_{j=1}^m n_j \zeta_j^2$.

Later on it is shown that

$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \left(1 - \frac{1}{N} \right) \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$$ is an unbiased estimate of the population variance $\sigma^2$, whose derivation I understand (by calculating $\text{E}[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2]$).

What I don't understand is, if $\text{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2$, why is just $\text{Var}(X_i)$ not an unbiased (exact) estimate of the population variance? As in, if the population variance is exactly the variance of my $X_i$'s, why can't I just calculate the variance of $X_i$ and the above result then guarantees that it will be equal to the population variance. I understand that if I calculate the expected value of $\text{Var}(X_i)$, I won't get exactly $\sigma^2$ (which is how you compute the correct unbiased estimator in the first place) but I'm trying to understand how to reconcile that with the result that the sample variance is exactly equal to the population variance. Isn't $\text{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2$ in conflict with the fact that naive sample variance is not an unbiased estimator of the population variance?